# ajax call to upload image is freezing the browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is code i am using to upload image to server using AJAX but for some reason the browser freezes till the image is uploaded. please someone tell me what's  the reason behind then problem and help me solve it.

```
$(function() {
    $("#form4").on('submit', function() {
        if($("#file").val()=== ""){
            alert("please select the image to upload");
            return false;
        }
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxify/uploadphoto.php',
            async:true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(".note").show().html("uploading....");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".note").html("uploaded successfully").fadeOut(2000);
                $('.galleryData').load('ajaxify/getphotos.php');
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This the html:

```
<form id="form4" action="ajaxify/uploadphoto.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <h2>upload album</h2>
    <label>select the file to upload</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    <div class="note"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: `async:false`. Change it to true

Comment: you have both `async:true` and `async:false` in your ajax call.  Remove `async:false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `async` is set to `false`, you are freezing the UI thread until the upload is complete.

Try changing it to `true`.

You can read about the property [in the API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).